# Python: Is there an easy way to replace a character in a string other than with replace()

Tags: python, string, list, replace

For one of my assignments I have to replace a token character with another character of my choosing, in a string. Oh, but replace() is not an option

I'm new to this, so please don't tear me apart too hard :)

```
def myReplace(content,token,new):
content = list(content)
newContent = []
newContent = list(newContent)
for item in content:
    if item == token:
        item = ''
        newContent[item].append[new]
return newContent
```

With the above, the intention is to check if every letter in the string matches the token character, and if it does, it is replaced with a new letter.

I have no idea what I need to add to this, or what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the character with index().
Concatenate the front, new char, and back.

```
pos = str.index(old_char)
newStr = str[:pos] + new_char + str[pos+1:]
```

If you have more than one occurrence of old_char, you can iterate until they're all done, or put this into a function and recur on the back part of the string.

Answer (score 3):

Well, since strings are iterable you can do this:

```
def my_replace(original, old, new):
    return "".join(x if not x == old else new for x in original)
```

Example:

```
>>> my_replace("reutsharabani", "r", "7")
'7eutsha7abani'
```

**Explanation:** This uses a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) to emit the new character whenever the old character is encountered, and uses `str.join` to join that expression with no separator (actually, empty string separator).

**Side note:** You can't actually mutate strings, that is why all solutions must construct a new string.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate through each character and substitute your token character. You could do this by building a string:

```
token = "$"
repl = "!"
s = "Hello, world$"

new_s = ""

for ch in s: 
    if ch == token:
        new_s += repl
    else:
        new_s += ch
```

Or using a generator with [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

```
def replacech(s, token, repl):
    for ch in s:
        if ch == token:
            yield repl
        else:
            yield ch

s = "Hello, World$"
new_s = ''.join(replacech(s, "$", "!"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def repl(st,token,new):
    ind = st.index(token)
    st = st[:ind] + new +st[ind + len(new):]
    return st

print(repl("anaconda","co","bo"))

anabonda
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions:

```
import re

token = '-'
str = 'foo-bar'
new_str = re.sub(token, '', str)
```

This results in:

```
boobar
```

Answer (score 0):

One-liner if you know of translate() and string.maketrans()

```
def myReplace(content, token, new):
    # Note: assumes token and new are single-character strings
    return content.translate(string.maketrans(token, new))
```